# Why friend custom operator<=> in class has a redefinition error and move the implement out of class will pass the compilation?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a class :

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept arithmetic = std::is_arithmetic<T>::value;

template <arithmetic Type>
class number
{
public:
    ...
private:
    Type _value;
}
```

and when I try to give out a custom operator<=> like this :

```cpp
class number
{
public:
    ...
    template <typename T, typename U>
    friend auto operator<=>(const number<T>& first, const number<U>& last)
    {
        return first._value <=> last._value;
    }
private:
    Type _value;
}
```

It will give out an error :

```cpp
<source>: In instantiation of 'class i::core::type::basic::number<double>':
<source>:106:20:   required from here
<source>:56:29: error: redefinition of 'template<class T, class U> auto i::core::type::basic::operator<=>(const number<T>&, const number<U>&)'
   56 |                 friend auto operator<=>(const number<T>& first, const number<U>& last)
      |                             ^~~~~~~~
<source>:56:29: note: 'template<class T, class U> auto i::core::type::basic::operator<=>(const number<T>&, const number<U>&)' previously declared here
<source>: In instantiation of 'auto i::core::type::basic::operator<=>(const number<T>&, const number<U>&) [with T = int; U = double; Type = int]':
<source>:107:28:   required from here
<source>:58:50: error: 'double i::core::type::basic::number<double>::_value' is private within this context
   58 |                     return first._value <=> last._value;
      |                                             ~~~~~^~~~~~
<source>:90:38: note: declared private here
   90 |                                 Type _value;
      |                                      ^~~~~~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In instantiation of 'class i::core::type::basic::number<double>':
<source>:106:20:   required from here
<source>:56:29: error: redefinition of 'template<class T, class U> auto i::core::type::basic::operator<=>(const number<T>&, const number<U>&)'
   56 |                 friend auto operator<=>(const number<T>& first, const number<U>& last)
      |                             ^~~~~~~~
<source>:56:29: note: 'template<class T, class U> auto i::core::type::basic::operator<=>(const number<T>&, const number<U>&)' previously declared here
<source>: In instantiation of 'auto i::core::type::basic::operator<=>(const number<T>&, const number<U>&) [with T = int; U = double; Type = int]':
<source>:107:28:   required from here
<source>:58:50: error: 'double i::core::type::basic::number<double>::_value' is private within this context
   58 |                     return first._value <=> last._value;
      |                                             ~~~~~^~~~~~
<source>:90:38: note: declared private here
   90 |                                 Type _value;
      |                                      ^~~~~~
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

But if I move the implement out of class like this :

```cpp
template <typename Type>
class number
{
public:
    template <typename T, typename U>
    friend auto operator<=>(const number<T>& first, const number<U>& last);
    ...
private:
    Type _value;
}
template <typename T, typename U>
friend auto operator<=>(const number<T>& first, const number<U>& last);
{
    return first._value <=> last._value;
}
```

It will pass the compilation.
Why redefination happened here?
And why moved the implement out of class scope will let it pass ?

Comment: [mcve] please! Also, is the `template` part relevant at all? How do you compile this even?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Question edited, thank you for ur reply :D

Comment: > why moved the implement out of class scope will let it pass?  Then you're `friend`-ing a *regular* function from outside to your class.